# How to create ratio or checkbox selection with DOMDocument?

Tags: php, html

With DOMDocument, I can create one radio input like this:

```
$html = new DOMDocument;
$radio = $html->createElement ( 'input' );
$radio->setAttribute ( 'type', 'radio' );
$radio->setAttribute ( 'name', 'test-ratio' );
$fieldset->appendChild ( $radio);
```

This will create a single radio input. When I have a list of choice, should I repeat the above code to create a list of radio input, or, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a new DomDocument to create radio buttons, just reuse the one you already have.

Also you can make one radio input and use [cloneNode](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.clonenode.php) make copies of them.

```
$radio = $html->createElement ( 'input' );
$radio->setAttribute ( 'name', 'test-ratio' );
$fieldset->appendChild ( $radio);
$fieldset->appendChild ( $radio->cloneNode());
```

Comment: so, if sometimes I need 3 radio, sometimes I need 4, then, I can add an argument of "n=3" or "n=4", use for( i=0 i<n i++ ) "$fieldset->appendChild ( $radio->cloneNode());" , is this alright?

Comment: @Jenny You can create the first one then use a loop to create the rest